# React performance problems with increasing number of components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, animation

**Turns out the problem was my computer. However, James made some good points about how to isolate the problem and utilizing useCallback and useMemo to optimize.**

I am having problems with the performance of my react app. For now I'm excluding the code because I feel there might be some common sense answers.

[This is the demo video](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cardboard-dev.appspot.com/o/publicRead%2Fsample2.mp4?alt=media&token=a06ba7d2-cb9a-478a-938e-1174543ff5b0)

Here some pointers

- I don't have unnecessary re-renders. Only individual components get rendered when they are hovered.
- The animations are confined to a container div of the hovered element so no re-paints happen on the page outside of that container when hovering.
- I am not using any heavy code for the hover effect or detection.

I am wondering what else could be cause for performance problems like this. As far as I understand, the number of components shouldn't matter if they are just sitting there, not rerendering.

Here is the code for the card component that is being animated. I wasn't quite sure whats important to show here. The parent component showing all the cards does not re-render.

```
export default function CardFile(props) {

    // Input field
    const input = useRef(null)

    //Input state
    const [inputActive, setInputActive] = useState(false);
    const [title, setTitle] = useState(props.file.name)
    const [menuActive, setMenuActive] = useState(false)

    const [draggable, setDraggable] = useState(true)
    const [isDragged, setIsDragged] = useState(false)

    // counter > 0 = is hovered
    const [dragCounter, setDragCounter] = useState(0)
    



    //_________________ FUNCTIONS _________________//
    
    // Handle file delete
    const handleDelete = (e) => {
        firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(props.file.owner).collection('files').doc(props.file.id).delete().then(() => {
            console.info('Deleted')
        }).catch((err) => console.err(err))
    }

    // Prevent default if necessary
    const preventDefault = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation()
    }

    // Handle rename
    const handleRename = (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation()
        setMenuActive(false)
        setInputActive(true)
    }

    // Handle change
    const handleChange = () => {
        setTitle(input.current.value)
    }

    // Handle focus loss
    const handleFocusLoss = (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation()
        setInputActive(false)
        firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(props.file.owner).collection('files').doc(props.file.id).update({ name: title })
            .then(() => {
                console.info('Updated title')
            }).catch((err) => console.error(err))
    }

    // Handle title submit
    const handleKeyPress = (e) => {
        console.log('key')
        if (e.code === "Enter") {
            e.preventDefault();

            setInputActive(false)
            firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(props.file.owner).collection('files').doc(props.file.id).update({ name: title })
                .then(() => {
                    console.info('Submitted title')
                }).catch((err) => console.error(err))
        }
    }

    // Set input focus
    useEffect(() => {
        if (inputActive) {
            input.current.focus()
            input.current.select()
        }
    }, [inputActive])


    //_____________________________DRAGGING___________________________//
    //Handle drag start
    const onDragStartFunctions = () => {
        props.onDragStart(props.file.id)
        setIsDragged(true)
    }
    // Handle drag enter
    const handleDragEnter = (e) => {
        // Only set as target if not equal to source
        if (!isDragged) {
            setDragCounter(dragCounter => dragCounter + 1)
        }
    }
    //Handle drag end
    const handleDragEnd = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setIsDragged(false)
    }
    // Handle drag exit
    const handleDragLeave = () => {
        // Only remove as target if not equal to source
        if (!isDragged) {
            setDragCounter(dragCounter => dragCounter - 1)
        }
    }
    // Handle drag over
    const handleDragOver = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
    }
    // Handle drag drop
    const onDragDropFunctions = (e) => {
        setDragCounter(0)
        // Only trigger when target if not equal to source
        if (!isDragged) {
            props.onDrop({
                id: props.file.id,
                display_type: 'file'
            })
        }
    }



    return (
        <div
            className={`${styles.card} ${dragCounter !== 0 && styles.is_hovered} ${isDragged && styles.is_dragged}`}
            test={console.log('render')}
            draggable={draggable}
            onDragStart={onDragStartFunctions}
            onDragEnter={handleDragEnter}
            onDragOver={handleDragOver}
            onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
            onDragLeave={handleDragLeave}
            onDrop={onDragDropFunctions}
        >
            <div className={styles.cardInner}>
                <div className={styles.videoContainer} onClick={() => props.handleActiveMedia(props.file, 'show')}>
                    {props.file.thumbnail_url && props.file.type === 'video' &&
                        <MdPlayCircleFilled className={styles.playButton} />
                    }
                    {!props.file.thumbnail_url && props.file.type === 'image' &&
                        <MdImage className={styles.processingButton} />
                    }
                    {!props.file.thumbnail_url && props.file.type === 'video' &&
                        <FaVideo className={styles.processingButton} />
                    }
                    <div className={styles.image} style={props.file.thumbnail_url && { backgroundImage: `url(${props.file.thumbnail_url})` }}></div>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.body}>
                    <div className={styles.main}>

                        {!inputActive ?
                            <p className={styles.title}>{title}</p>
                            :
                            <input
                                ref={input}
                                className={styles.titleInput}
                                type="text"
                                onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                onBlur={handleFocusLoss}
                                defaultValue={title}
                            />
                        }
                    </div>

                    <ToggleContext onClick={() => setMenuActive(prevMenuActive => !prevMenuActive)}>
                        {
                            menuActive && <div className={styles.menuBackground} />
                        }
                        <Dropdown top small active={menuActive}>
                            <ButtonLight title={'Rename'} icon={<MdTitle />} onClick={handleRename} />
                            <ButtonLight title={'Label'} icon={<MdLabel />} onClick={() => props.handleActiveMedia(props.file, 'label')} />
                            <ButtonLight title={'Share'} icon={<MdShare />} onClick={() => window.alert("Sharing is not yet supported. Stay put.")} />
                            {/*props.file.type === 'video' && <ButtonLight title={'Split'} icon={<RiScissorsFill />} />*/}
                            <ButtonLightConfirm
                                danger
                                title={'Delete'}
                                icon={<MdDelete />}
                                onClick={(e) => preventDefault(e)}
                                confirmAction={handleDelete}
                                preventDrag={() => setDraggable(false)}
                                enableDrag={() => setDraggable(true)}
                            />
                        </Dropdown>
                    </ToggleContext>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    );
}
```

And here is the css for animating it:

```
.is_hovered {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px var(--blue);
}
.is_hovered > div {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    transition: .1s;
}
```

**Edit: Added code**

**Edit2: Updated sample video to show re-renders**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing I think you should try first is 'memoizing' all your functions with `useCallback`. Especially as you're passing some of these functions down to other components, it's possible they are causing unnecessary re-rendering deeper in the DOM.

I don't know if you're familiar with `useCallback`, but basically it just wraps around your function, and only updates it when specific values change. This allows React to avoid re-creating it on every render and causing components deeper in the DOM to re-render.

You can read the docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback), but the gist of it is that instead of `const getA = () => a` you would write `getA = useCallback(() => a, [a])`, and the array contains all the dependencies for the function which cause it to update if changed.

Make sure you use these in your JSX, and avoid arrow functions like `onClick={(e) => preventDefault(e)}`. The function you have called `preventDefault` can even live outside the component entirely, since it makes no reference to anything specific to the component.

Try making these updates and see if it makes a difference. Also test without the `console.log`, since that can also slow things down.

Comment: I actually didn't know about useCallback. I implemented your suggestion and wrapped all the functions. It did make for a slight performance improvement but unfortunately nothing major. What confuses me is that the performance is somehow tied to the number of card elements on the page when dev tools tells me that only the card being hovered is re-rendered.

Comment: Ok, so I commented out everything inside the wrapper div (but left the dragEvents). Everything works smoothly like this, even with many cards on the screen. Do you still want the parent code in that context? Also, are there any expensive operations inside the card component that stand out to you? Things like passing components as props, etc. I'm new to React so I probably don't know about a bunch of things that seem ok to me but might be detrimental to performance. I also edited the video in my original question so you can see the render flashes. Thanks so much for looking into this!

Comment: I just finished deactivating child elements both one by one, and in groups. It does seem like every child is contributing somewhat evenly to the overall slowdown. What confuses me is that the number of card components on screen has a correlative, negative impact on the performance when dev tools shows that no cards except the ones being interacted with, ever re-render. Especially given that the parent doesn't change and therefore wouldn't trigger any changes in the child components.

Comment: No big secrets here. Feel free to have a look at the repository https://github.com/maxibenner/cardboard. The culprits are the "browse" container and the "CardFile" component. You can use the test credentials from the Readme to dive straight into an account with a bunch of files.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I removed the live key. Thought for the dev key the risk is worth it so people can get it running right away. Are you running it on a faster computer? Mine is a 5 year old, entry level MacBook Pro. Not the fastest but I was assuming it should be able to handle a small React app with basic css animations at 60fps.

Comment: I just realized that, while the performance could be a bit better on Safari, it is definitely much worse on Chrome.

Comment: I just ran a test on two other computers and the performance seems good. No idea what happened to my computer. Sorry for wasting your time with this. However, if you happen to find any kind of performance optimization, I'd be happy to accept it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for looking into it. Under any other circumstance your answer would have been a good way to approach the problem.